# Installing smart switch, instructions say to add capacitor in parallel for optimal performance

Tags: electrical, switch, smart-switch

I have bought [this wireless two-way switch](https://chacon.com/en/switches-connected/2151-connected-plug-dio-connect-5411478549567.html) to add a second switch to an existing light. The instructions say:

> 1. Connect L (brown or red) to terminal L of the module.
> 2. Connect the cable from the bulb (brown or red) to the L1 terminal of the module.
> 3. Connect the capacitor in parallel to the bulb for optimal operation.

I have two questions:

- How do I know which cable is coming from the bulb? Does it really matter?
- What difference does the capacitor make?

I haven't yet looked but I'm not certain it will be clear which cable is which, and there won't be room for the capacitor provided.

Just in case it helps:

- this is in France
- the building is from 2004
- the switch is for a single light fitting which has four cheap LEDs mounted in it

Comment: You will need to open the switch plate up on the wall to look. It's possible that the cables will be identified in the wall, but not likely. You'll have to do some sleuthing with a voltage meter or a non-contact voltage detector.

Comment: At a minimum, turn off power (at the breaker/consumer unit) to this light, open it up, pull the switch out of the wall (do _NOT_ disconnect any wiring!), then take clear, focused pictures of the switch and all the wiring, then [edit] them into your question. From there, someone will likely be able to guide you on the next steps.